# Unstacking column according to two other columns

Tags: pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
df 
     resid      familyid age
54  -0.855952    1028/2  39
55  -0.733972    1028/2  40
56  -0.821011    1028/2  41
57  -0.759187    1028/2  42
58  -0.753066    1028/2  43
65   1.268154    1028/2  35
66   1.214893    1028/2  36
...etc
```

*resid* contains N floating point numbers. *familyid* contains different identifiers (keys) like shown above and age contains 10 values: from 35 to 44. Each *familyid* is represented twice in this data (i.e they are siblings), and I wish to transform this dataframe to a 2*10 column dataframe where:

The first column contains all the *resid* values for the first *age* 35 siblings, the second column contains all *resid* values for the second *age* 35 siblings, the third column contains all the *resid* values for the first *age* 36 sibling, etc.

I hope this was clear. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to do that is to `tag` each sibling as `1` (first) or `2` (second) and then pivot; for example starting with

```
>>> df
    resid familyid  age
0   -0.86   1028/2   39
1   -0.73   1028/2   40
2   -0.82   1028/2   41
3   -0.76   1028/2   42
4   -0.75   1028/2   43
5    1.27   1028/2   35
6    1.21   1028/2   36
7    1.71   1028/2   39
8    1.47   1028/2   40
9    1.64   1028/2   41
10   1.52   1028/2   42
11   1.51   1028/2   43
12  -2.54   1028/2   35
13  -2.43   1028/2   36
```

the tagging part can be done by

```
>>> tagfn = lambda x: 1 + np.arange(len(x))
>>> df['tag'] = df.groupby(['familyid', 'age']).transform(tagfn)
```

and then:

```
>>> df.pivot_table('resid', 'familyid', ['age', 'tag'])
age         35          36          39          40          41          42          43      
tag          1     2     1     2     1     2     1     2     1     2     1     2     1     2
familyid                                                                                    
1028/2    1.27 -2.54  1.21 -2.43 -0.86  1.71 -0.73  1.47 -0.82  1.64 -0.76  1.52 -0.75  1.51

[1 rows x 14 columns]
```